# setTimeout работает с разной скоростью

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

Всем привет, хочу разобраться в вопросе, ответ на который не могу найти.
Решил для практики написать небольшую игру, где игрок должен находить одинаковые пары карт, кликая по ним.
[Ссылка на репозиторий](https://github.com/danil0110/MatchingGame)
[Ссылка на игру](https://danil0110.github.io/MatchingGame/)
Фрагмент кода, который у меня вызывает вопрос:

```
const openCard = (card) => {
    if (chooses.length < 2) {
        chooses.push(card);
        let front = card.querySelector('*');
        card.classList.remove('closed');
        front.classList.remove('closed');
        card.classList.add('opened');
        front.classList.add('opened');
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
        if (chooses.length === 2) {
            if (!isMatched(chooses[0], chooses[1])) {
                closeChosenCards();
                chooses = [];
            }
            else {
                matchCount++;
                if (isEnd()) {
                    endGame();
                }
            }
            chooses = [];
        }
    }, 1500)
}
```

При перевороте игроком очередной карты проверяется подняты ли на текущий момент 2 карты, и если да - идет проверка на сопоставление пары. Если карты не одинаковые, то карты переворачиваются обратно, и здесь стоит `setTimeout(..., 1500)`, чтобы это не происходило моментально и игрок увидел, что карты не одинаковые.
Бывает, что карты переворачиваются с нормальной задержкой, но бывает и так, что они переворачиваются после долгой задержки или вообще чуть ли не моментально. Почему так происходит и как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы запускаете setTimeout после первого (точнее после любого) клика, а надо только после второго клика

Comment: @andreymal глупая ошибка, спасибо! У меня проверка на количество внутри таймаута, когда правильнее после проверки его запускать. Теперь работает как надо.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в том, что проверка на количество открытых карт находилась непосредственно внутри `setTimeout`, когда логичнее запускать `setTimeout` после проверки.

```
if (chooses.length === 2) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (!isMatched(chooses[0], chooses[1])) {
            closeChosenCards();
            chooses = [];
        }
        else {
            matchCount++;
            if (isEnd()) {
                endGame();
            }
        }
        chooses = [];
    }, 1500);
}
```